# Adding Rows and Columns to a WPF DataGrid at Run-Time

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

All, I am new to WPF. I want to read a .resx file and all the related files with different cultures; for example a default 'en-GB' .resx file called 'SomeFile.resx' and 'SomeFile.de-DE.resx' the German analogue. Of course I could have a vast number of different .resx files relating to various cultures.

So, I want to read all the different culture resources into a single `DataGrid`, so that I have something like

```
Resource Index | Resource Key | English (Default) | German
1              | SomeKey1     | Run Script        | Skript Ausführen 
2              | SomeKey2     | OK                | OK
```

et al. My problem is the best way to add this data to a `DataGrid` called `dataGrid`. So I currently get the available non-default .resx file into a `Dictionary<string, string>`

```
Dictionary<string, string> cultureDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Then I plan to loop through the different .resx files (for the numerous cultures) using an `ResXResourceReader` to read the .resx files like so

```
Dictionary<string, string> resourceMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public static void Func(string fileName)
{
    ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(fileName);        
    foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
    {
        resourceMap.Add(d.Key.ToString(),d.Value.ToString());           
    }        
    rsxr.Close();
}

public string GetResource(string resourceId)
{
    return resourceMap[resourceId];
}
```

I had planned to create a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` to hold the information from the readers for the different culture and then loop through the `List`, and add the rows.

My question is **What is the best and most efficient way to put the data returned from these readers into the `DataGrid` bearing in mind the number of cultures is variable and potentially large?**

Thanks for your time.

*Note: I can add the columns*

```
DataGridTextColumn itemColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
itemColumn.Header = "Item Number";
itemColumn.Binding = new Binding("Item Number");
dataGrid.Columns.Add(itemColumn);
```

*But it is the best way to add the rows for this particular case.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void Display_Grid(DataGrid d, List<string> S1)
{
    ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    DataColumn cl = new DataColumn("Item Number", typeof(string));
    cl.MaxLength = 200;
    dt.Columns.Add(cl);

    int i = 0;
    foreach (string s in S1)
    {
        DataRow rw = dt.NewRow();
        rw["Item Number"] = S1[i];
        i++;
    }
    d.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].AsDataView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add new row in datagrid using observablecollection ItemCollection

```
    itemmodel model=new itemmodel ();
model.name='Rahul';
ItemCollection.add(model);
```